# SKSpriteNode with texture showing white background

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uiimage

I'm adding a `SKSpriteNode` to a scene, and the original image size is showing up as a white background.

Here's my code

```
    let imageNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, size: CGSize(width: 63, height: 63))
    imageNode.position = self.anchorPoint
    addChild(imageNode)
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

The size adjustment works great, but there's that strange white background.

Comment: What extension does your image have?

Comment: .png, I thought it might be an alpha problem at first, but if I put a colored shape node underneath the spriteNode, the shape node shows just fine, but the white rectangle is still behind it.

Comment: Okay that sounds good (as long as it have really transparent background).Do you have any nodes added to GameScene.sks file?

Comment: Nope, that node is actually moving and the white square moves with it.

Comment: Okay. So what is the size of a node? Can you print that? Or, can you upload minimal project to Github which can reproduce the issue? And do one Product -> Clean (or Simulator -> reset content and settings if you are testing on Simulator).

Comment: Ok, so it turns out that on my overriding `init(texture:)' I was passing in a blank image to `super.init' and I just had to change the size of it. So basically the image I wanted was being drawn correctly, but there was also another blank image being drawn below.